# BeagleBoneBlack PRU from Scratch

Tags: texas-instruments, beaglebone-black, soc, real-time

I am a newbie when it comes to embedded systems and I am an even bigger newbie when it comes to working with the BeagleBone Black (Rev C in my case). I want to play and discover the PRU on the BBB, but it proves to be a more confusing task than I imagined because a lot of things on the net seem outdated.

What are the steps to take to get the PRU working (a blinky to begin with, even though my interest lies in figuring out how to communicate with the PRU using the shared memory) considering I have a fresh and clean BBB Rev C in hand (new Debian).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but requests for pointers to external resources are off topic here.

Comment: Hey @ChrisStratton. Thank you for the reply. Where should I post this? I will try to modify the question in the meantime.

Comment: @sobosama You're best off just searching for the original manual for the PRU so then asking something specific in them.

Comment: Also, when you say "from scratch" I interpret that as "bare metal" which means no OS. Just your own code which is a daunting task with something like the Beaglebone processor. I'm assuming that's not really what you mean (or maybe it is?) and you mean you just want to write code for the PRU.

Comment: I assume you have seen this? http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter15/

Comment: Hey @DKNguyen from Scratch I mean like if we have a clean BBB (just the Debian installed on it). I quickly went over the link you sent earlier and I have a feeling it's outdated?

Comment: You should not have duplicated this on stackoverflow!   The problem with the question is that it does not fit the purpose of the stack exchange network.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, apologies for that I just wasn't sure where should it go. I will delete the one from stack overflow.